# nodejs - save account information inside .env file or in client side database

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, dotenv, nedb

I've created a simple nodejs app that will use express to do some file processing operations. I will pack the final app using [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg) this mean that the app will access the packaged resources in readonly mode. Since I want to implement a login system and a one time account creation, what's the best way to proceed? The app will open a browser tab that will run the a vuejs app for the UI. I'm thinking to use [nedb-promises](https://github.com/bajankristof/nedb-promises) by implementing it in the vue app but the data stored inside it are accessible to all so the login will become insecure. Is there a way to encrypt/decrypt stored data inside nedb-promises?

Another solution I'm thinking to use is to run the one time account creation and to store the created account info inside a `.env` file that will be created inside the folder where te app will run. With this method how I can hash password and account data and when the app is launched check them with the credential that the user will input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NeDB have two functions called `beforeDeserialization` and `afterSerialization`. These can be used for encrypting and decrypting data when reading and writing from your database using the `crypto` module.

```
const crypto    = require('crypto');
const Datastore = require('nedb-promises');

const ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-cbc'
const BLOCK_SIZE = 16
const SECRET = 'SECRET'

const database = new Datastore({
    filename: 'database.db', 
    autoload: true,
    afterSerialization (plaintext) {
        // Encryption

        const iv = crypto.randomBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, SECRET, iv);
        const ciphertext = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(plaintext), cipher.final()]);
        return ciphertext.toString('base64');
    },
    beforeDeserialization (ciphertext) {
        // Decryption

        const ciphertextBytes = Buffer.from(ciphertext, 'base64');
        const iv = ciphertextBytes.slice(0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        const data = ciphertextBytes.slice(BLOCK_SIZE);
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, SECRET, iv);
        const plaintextBytes = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(data), decipher.final()]);
        return plaintextBytes.toString('utf8');
    },
});
```

You would want to your `SECRET` variable to be a random generated string stored in a `.env` file